# How to communicate between GoogleNACL and a c# application

Tags: c#, message, google-nativeclient

Can any one put me in the right direction.

in our php web application, we need to have the ability of scanning documents from teh scanner connected to the computer.

With the currect workflow when we want to scan,

1. they have to get a token from our webserver.
2. they have to open our c# desktop app and then enter the token and then scan . once scanned we are posting it to server and the server will handle the file based on the token.

is there any way using google NACL  , we can pass message to the c# desktop application and execute it ?